# PHP and AJAX Web Content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am thinking of developing a website in PHP and I was thinking of using AJAX in order to send data to, and retrieve data from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

So my question:  would it be better to use AJAX to GET or POST to php pages or any other options are possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not that many options when it comes to submiting data, either you use AJAX or use the normal http message like GET or POST. If you would like to determin witch is better i would say: **it depends**.

Ajax seems to me like a great way of making more dynamic a part of your site, but i dont think its always practical to use in all your site. Ajax is generally used when you need to show some context change on one page, like posting a commner, faving a question, or things like that. Another great thing about it is not to bound user to a form (you can save info with a link like when you vote a question here)

Using GET or POST its usefull to let the user now here's moving along a process or when things that happen after or before are different, or context change a lot when submitting.

Comment: Thanks. Hey mind explaining to me how do sites like youtube and google chrome web store works? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I think that there is no real answer to that question,  i would love to know, but i really dont, sorry :P. Those site you mention are always working on edgy technology so you never now how are they build specifically

Comment: Yeh, this question always circles around my mind like how was Google build, how was YouTube, how was FB developed, Was Google Chrome Web Store built with PHP, Jquery or ASP. I guess there is no real answer to that unless Ur the one who worked on these web development.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb (regardless of AJAX).

If you're going to send large amounts of data, or sensitive data... POST.
Otherwise, GET works just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use JQuery.
with $.ajax of Jquery, you can use it with multiple options depending that you need.
So you can work with POST, GET, receive data like text, json...

Here you can get more info:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. But do i need to consider anything in mind while using $.ajax of jquery to php?

Comment: i believe that ajax is better, i don't found another form to do some like you need. i usually use method GET, the POST only use to send form without AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

I always use `$_POST`.  I wish I could give a reason why I think it's better, but I can't.  I guess it's because I've always preferred sending data via POST rather than GET so the user doesn't see it, and it just carried over to my ajax.

Comment: Yes, i aggree with you but you can't use POST all the time. There are some time when you are needed to use GET.

Answer (score -1):

I would use `$_POST` just for the fact that it can store more data.